# How to ensure a child component is not always reloaded when different parent components are mounted in Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

[image]

Just as it is in the image provided, there is a child component being imported to every the parent components (Pdetails, Education, Dependents...etc). One major challenge I'm having is that when ever I route to any of these component, `axios` sends a get request which loads the same content into the child component and I'm believing it's not good for performance. Is there a way to do it just once?

Secondly, how can I share data returned from an API in the child component with the parent component.

This is the child component

```
<template>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
       <div class="card-box text-center">
           <img src="/assets/images/users/user-1.jpg" class="rounded-circle avatar-lg img-thumbnail" alt="profile-image">
           <h4 class="mb-0"> {{  employee.surname }} {{  employee.first_name }} </h4>
           <p class=" mb-2 font-13"><strong><i class="fe-mail text-info"></i> :</strong> <span class="ml-2 ">{{employee.email}}</span></p>
          <p class=" mb-1 font-13"><strong><i class="fe-layers text-danger"></i> :</strong><span class="ml-2">{{employee.age}}</span></p>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- end col-->

</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'EmployeeCard',
    data(){
        return{
            employee: {
                job: '', 
                state:'',
                company: ''
            },

        }
    },
    methods:{
        getUser(){
            axios.get('/api/users/'+ this.$route.params.id)
                .then ( response => {
                    this.employee = response.data.data[0].data; 
                })
        }
    },

    mounted(){

        this.getUser();
    }

}
</script>
```

And below is the personalDetail component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <EmployeeCard /> <!-- Can I get data from this child component to this component? -->
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-xl-9">
                    <div class="card text-center">
                        <ProfileNav />                    
                        <div class="card-body">

                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- end card-box-->
                </div>
        </div>       
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>

</style>
<script>
import ProfileNav from "../nav/ProfileNav";
import EmployeeCard from "./EmployeeCard";
export default {
    name: 'PDetails',

    components:{
        ProfileNav, EmployeeCard
    },


    //every component must return something
    data(){
        return {

        }
    },



}
</script>
```

I want to share data like `employee.first_name` from the EmployeeCard to this EmployeeShow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can by emiting en event from the child to the parent.

in the child component :

```js
        getUser(){
            axios.get('/api/users/'+ this.$route.params.id)
                .then ( response => {
                    this.employee = response.data.data[0].data; 
                    this.$emit('setEmployee', this.employee);
                }) 
        }
```

In personalDetail component :

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <EmployeeCard @setEmployee="setEmployee"/> <!-- Can I get data from this child component to this component? -->
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-xl-9">
                    <div class="card text-center">
                        <ProfileNav />                    
                        <div class="card-body">

                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- end card-box-->
                </div>
        </div>       
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>

</style>
<script>
import ProfileNav from "../nav/ProfileNav";
import EmployeeCard from "./EmployeeCard";
export default {
    name: 'PDetails',

    components:{
        ProfileNav, EmployeeCard
    },
    methods: {
      setEmployee(event) {
        this.employee = event;
      }
    }

    //every component must return something
    data(){
        return {
            employee: null
        }
    },



}
</script>
```

I think that [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) solve the problem of loading the same data twice.

With vuex you can create a store where you will keep the information that you want to use anywhere else in your application.

Comment: Very nice answer, you have solved one problem. Thanks so much

Comment: I will not fail to do that.. Although the part A is pending.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do it just once?

Vue is pretty good at reusing component instances during an update. In this case since the parent component is changing, the child components within it will also be reinitialized. There isn't much you can do to prevent this from happening.

`<keep-alive>` can be used to keep each parent instance alive, which means each child will only be created one time for each parent. This is better, but still not most optimal.

I would suggest you raise the data fetching logic into a parent component and then pass the data down to the child via props. That way the child components won't be fetching the data over and over again each time they are initialized.

Alternatively you can use a data store (e.g. Vuex) so that the data will be persisted externally from the child component and then you can conditionally fetch the data if you have not already done so.

> Secondly, how can I share data returned from an API in the child component with the parent component.

Again, I would suggest you raise the data fetching logic to the parent. It makes more sense for the parent component to "own" the data and then pass it down to child components that need to display it, rather than an inverted relationship where the child fetches the data and then passes it up to the parent via events. That can get messy real quick.